# read_csv: all my data is read as objects/strings

Tags: python

I have a csv file with the character ';' as a separator. The fact is that in this file (about 100,000 rows and 30 columns or so), most values ​​are float, except for a "date" column and some "NaN".

```
url = "data.csv"
dataset = pandas.read_csv (url, sep = ';', names = names, skiprows = 1, low_memory = False)
```

By calling the read_csv function, I get a dataframe where with only objects (strings), when what I really want is to automatically detect the types of each column. I tried to add the dtype option, but I get the message:

> Cannot cast array from dtype ('O') to dtype ('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

Anyone have an idea of ​​what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!!

Comment: Can you confirm that after reading the file that `dataset.dtypes` does indeed show all objects and that columns expected to be float aren't?

Comment: Yes Jon, I confirm, this command show me all objects, event the columns expected to be float. Thks in advance!

Comment: Hi Renate, this does not answer my question since I already tried the dtype option. As explained, I get the following message : "Cannot cast array from dtype ('O') to dtype ('float64') according to the rule 'safe'"